# In VB .NET 2015, when autofocusing on the Datetimepicker and changing the time, it changes the hours

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a datetimepicker with custom formatting. When I don't click the minute value, but just change the time with the up & down buttons, it always starts changing the hour value instead of the minute value.
Automatically changing the minute value would be much better, at least with the program I'm working on.

How can I change this default setting?

[A short gif explaining the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsVhC.gif)

Comment: You cannot directly control the focus on the elements yourself.  A hack is to use SendKeys in an event handler for the Enter event.

Answer (score 0):

Hans Passant's answer about using the `SendKeys.Send`-command in the Enter-event technically works, but then the caret switches between the hour and minute values every time the DateTimePicker is entered/left.

But I figured out a solution:

This is assuming that the DateTimePicker's Format is set to Custom.
When the DateTimePicker's DateTimePickerFormat is changed to `DateTimePickerFormat.Time` and right back to `DateTimePickerFormat.Custom`, the caret resets to the hour, so after switching the DateTimePickerFormat back and forth once, we can use the `SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}")` without worrying about it switching back to the hour value.

Now this most certainly is a hack, so you'll need to include some code for special situations, but here's the code in its simplicity:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.Enter
    DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time
    DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}")
End Sub
```